# Override Android's Gmail app minimum font-size (Newsletter)

Tags: android, css, fonts, html-email

I am creating a newsletter and after a lot of effort it works everywhere except android's gmail app. The problem is that it seems it has a minimum font size and that cause my table to break.

Is there a way to overcome the minimum font-size not with media queries cause most likely it will get stripped.

In iphone's Mail app for instance, to overcome the minimum font-size I use `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;` 
Is there something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check this thread? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7801/gmail-app-android-text-size/ as it's said there:

> You need to add min-width to a container table (one that wraps all your other tables, NOT your 100% container) then you should see most, if not all auto fit issues dissapear since most auto-fit issues are related in some way to the device independent pixel (DIP) width.

Comment: No, I did not check that. I don't have a template and Android phone to check for now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't an auto-fit issue. It's true that the min-width fix will make your layout arrange correctly, but I'm pretty sure the issue with the text is a combination of the GMail app not respecting webkit-font-size-adjust, stripping any viewport tags, moving any <13px font up to 13px. I've tried a lot of things for this in the past :( i've been reduced to making images out of small text / nesting tables as a container to account for more text space than every other client.

Tested in Litmus and GMail on Android 4.3

Comment: Yes I understand how valuable min-width is for emails, I used it a lot. From my research till now my question has no really answer only an alternative, for instance if you want to use a menu with small font-size you could use an image for that or redesign your email (the second would be better)